# Trying to generate a list from a JSON object (TypeError list indices must be integers or slices, not str)

Tags: python, json

I have retrieved a JSON object from an API. The JSON object looks like this:

```
{'copyright': 'Copyright (c) 2020 The New York Times Company. All Rights '
              'Reserved.',
 'response': {'docs': [{'_id': 'nyt://article/e3e5e5e5-1b32-5e2b-aea7-cf20c558dbd3',
                        'abstract': 'LEAD: RESEARCHERS at the Brookhaven '
                                    'National Laboratory are employing a novel '
                                    'model to study skin cancer in humans: '
                                    'they are exposing tiny tropical fish to '
                                    'ultraviolet radiation.',
                        'byline': {'organization': None,
                                   'original': 'By Eric Schmitt',
                                   'person': [{'firstname': 'Eric',
                                               'lastname': 'Schmitt',
                                               'middlename': None,
                                               'organization': '',
                                               'qualifier': None,
                                               'rank': 1,
                                               'role': 'reported',
                                               'title': None}]},
                        'document_type': 'article',
                        'headline': {'content_kicker': None,
                                     'kicker': None,
                                     'main': 'Tiny Fish Help Solve Cancer '
                                             'Riddle',
                                     'name': None,
                                     'print_headline': 'Tiny Fish Help Solve '
                                                       'Cancer Riddle',
                                     'seo': None,
                                     'sub': None},
                        'keywords': [{'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'organizations',
                                      'rank': 1,
                                      'value': 'Brookhaven National '
                                               'Laboratory'},
                                     {'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'subject',
                                      'rank': 2,
                                      'value': 'Ozone'},
                                     {'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'subject',
                                      'rank': 3,
                                      'value': 'Radiation'},
                                     {'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'subject',
                                      'rank': 4,
                                      'value': 'Cancer'},
                                     {'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'subject',
                                      'rank': 5,
                                      'value': 'Research'},
                                     {'major': 'N',
                                      'name': 'subject',
                                      'rank': 6,
                                      'value': 'Fish and Other Marine Life'}],
                        'lead_paragraph': 'RESEARCHERS at the Brookhaven '
                                          'National Laboratory are employing a '
                                          'novel model to study skin cancer in '
                                          'humans: they are exposing tiny '
                                          'tropical fish to ultraviolet '
                                          'radiation.',
                        'multimedia': [],
                        'news_desk': 'Science Desk',
                        'print_page': '3',
                        'print_section': 'C',
                        'pub_date': '1989-12-26T05:00:00+0000',
                        'section_name': 'Science',
                        'snippet': '',
                        'source': 'The New York Times',
                        'type_of_material': 'News',
                        'uri': 'nyt://article/e3e5e5e5-1b32-5e2b-aea7-cf20c558dbd3',
                        'web_url': 'https://www.nytimes.com/1989/12/26/science/tiny-fish-help-solve-cancer-riddle.html',
                        'word_count': 870},
                       {'_id': 'nyt://article/32a2431d-623a-525b-a21d-d401be865818',
                        'abstract': 'LEAD: Clouds, even the ones formed by '
```

...and continues like that, too long to show all of it here.

Now, when I want to list just one headline, I use:

```
pprint(articles['response']['docs'][0]['headline']['print_headline'])
```

And I get the output

```
'Tiny Fish Help Solve Cancer Riddle'
```

The problem is when I want to pick out all of the headlines from this JSON object, and make a list of them. I tried:

```
index = 0
for headline in articles:
    headlineslist = ['response']['docs'][index]['headline']['print_headline'].split("''")
    index = index + 1
headlineslist
```

But I get the error TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

In other words, it worked when I "listed" just one headline, at index [0], but not when I try to repeat the process over each index. How do I iterate through each index to get a list of outputs like the first one?

Comment: It's unclear to me why you thought `for headline in articles:` would iterate over the list `articles["response"]["docs"]`.

Comment: What do you expect `['response']['docs']` to evaluate to?

Comment: You're not referencing the variable `headline` in the `for headline in articles:` loop.

Comment: Please provide the **entire** error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To iterate over the document list you can just do the following:

```
for doc in (articles['response']['docs']):
    print(doc['headline']['print_headline'])
```

This would print all headlines.

Comment: Ah, I see. So to generalize: are you saying that everything that comes before the variable index is the list itself, and after the variable index is the separate line items?

Comment: `articles['response']['docs']` returns a list. The `for doc in ...` iterates over this list.  Each item is a dictionary. Then we extract the value for the key 'headline'. This value is again a dictionary, where we extract the desired string value for the key 'print_headline'.